# `std::function` returning a `concept`

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Proceeding with my studies on `concepts`, and after looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70425137/exporting-template-function-requiring-std-concepts), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527461/using-c20-concepts-to-avoid-stdfunction) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903428/function-concept-return-type-must-be-bool), among other pages, I wonder how could I declare a function type that  returns a `std::optional` of another `concept`, like below:

```
template <typename t>
concept event = requires(t p_t) {
    { t::id } -> std::same_as<const size_t &>;
    requires std::default_initializable<t>;
};

using func = std::function<std::optional<event>(int)>;
```

`gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0` reports `Too few template arguments for concept 'event'`

I tried

```
template <typename t>
using func = std::function<std::optional<event<t>>(int)>;
```

which generated the error `Template argument for template type parameter must be a type`

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: No, `std::function`'s argument must be a single specific type, known at compile time. You can use the `invocable` concept, though, to generalize `std::function` (you may also want to make it copyable, etc).

Comment: Something like this?


    template <typename t>
    concept event = requires(t p_t) {
      { t::id } -> std::same_as<const size_t &>;
      requires std::default_initializable<t>;
    };

    template <typename t_functor, typename t_event>
    concept func = requires(t_functor p_functor, t_event p_event) {
        event<t_event> && 
        std::invocable<t_functor, int> &&
        std::same_as<typename std::invoke_result_t<t_functor, int>, t_event> &&
        std::copy_constructible<t_functor>;
    };



I am sorry, but I could get it properly formated

Comment: You mean `template <event T>
using func = std::function<std::optional<T>(int)>;`?

Comment: Wow! That is it. So much simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. A concept is **not** a type. It's purpose is to make setting constraints easier (for example in contexts where you'd use `std::enable_if` pre C++20).

Example:

```cpp
// Pre C++20 SFINAE
template<typename T>
struct event_sfinae {
    static constexpr bool value = ...;
};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<event_sfinae<T>::value>>
void foo1(T arg) {
    ...
}

// C++20 concept version
template<typename T>
concept event_concept = ...; // Define concept

template<event_concept T> // only types that satisfy the constraints of 'event_concept' allowed
void foo2(T arg) {
    ...
}
```